# Select query php sql injection

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing a test on a code that I had previously written, my goal is to write safer queries but I don't understand why it doesn't work

working query:

```
$zero = 0;
$inviata = "SI";
$token_inserito = "NO";
$richiesta_non_scaduta = "NO";
$categoria_professionista = $_SESSION['categoria_collaboratore'];
$oggi = date('Y-m-d');
$query_string = "SELECT *
                 FROM richieste
                 LEFT JOIN cat_professionisti
                 ON richieste.categoria_richiesta = cat_professionisti.ID_cat_prof
                 WHERE richieste.categoria_richiesta = cat_professionisti.ID_cat_prof
                 AND richieste.ID_Collaboratore = 0
                 AND richieste.inviata = 'SI'
                 AND richieste.token_inserito = 'NO'
                 AND richieste.richiesta_scaduta = 'NO'
                 AND richieste.categoria_richiesta = '$categoria_professionista'
                 AND richieste.scadenza_richiesta >= '$oggi' 
";

$query_richieste_disponibili = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_richieste_disponibili)){ ?>
......
<?php } ?>
```

query not working:

```
$zero = 0;
$inviata = "SI";
$token_inserito = "NO";
$richiesta_non_scaduta = "NO";
$categoria_professionista = $_SESSION['categoria_collaboratore'];
$oggi = date('Y-m-d');

$query = $connessione->prepare("
SELECT *
             FROM richieste
             LEFT JOIN cat_professionisti
             ON richieste.categoria_richiesta = cat_professionisti.ID_cat_prof
             WHERE richieste.categoria_richiesta = cat_professionisti.ID_cat_prof
             AND richieste.ID_Collaboratore = ?
             AND richieste.inviata = ?
             AND richieste.token_inserito = ?
             AND richieste.richiesta_scaduta = ?
             AND richieste.categoria_richiesta = ?
             AND richieste.scadenza_richiesta >= ?");

$query->bind_param('isssii', $zero, $inviata, $token_inserito, $richiesta_non_scaduta, $categoria_professionista, $oggi);

$query_richieste_disponibili = $query->execute();

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_richieste_disponibili)){ ?>
......
<?php } ?>
```

as I repeat my intent is to write queries against sql injection and therefore safer

edit for @**Barmar**

```
$zero = 0;
$inviata = "SI";
$token_inserito = "NO";
$richiesta_non_scaduta = "NO";
$categoria_professionista = $_SESSION['categoria_collaboratore'];
$oggi = date('Y-m-d');


    $query = $connessione->prepare("
             SELECT *
             FROM richieste
             LEFT JOIN cat_professionisti
             ON richieste.categoria_richiesta = cat_professionisti.ID_cat_prof
             WHERE richieste.categoria_richiesta = cat_professionisti.ID_cat_prof
             AND richieste.ID_Collaboratore = ?
             AND richieste.inviata = ?
             AND richieste.token_inserito = ?
             AND richieste.richiesta_scaduta = ?
             AND richieste.categoria_richiesta = ?
             AND richieste.scadenza_richiesta >= ?");

    $query->bind_param('isssii', $zero, $inviata, $token_inserito, $richiesta_non_scaduta, $categoria_professionista, $oggi);

    $query_richieste_disponibili = $query->execute();
                    <?php
                    if ($query->execute()) {
                        $query_richieste_disponibili = $query->get_result();

                        while($row = $query_richieste_disponibili->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                            <?php }
                        } ?>
```

I followed your code that you kindly wrote together with the explanation but when I report it it doesn't work, where am I wrong?

Comment: You don't need to repeat `richieste.categoria_richiesta = cat_professionisti.ID_cat_prof` in the `WHERE` clause, doing it in the `ON` clause is enough.

Comment: @Barmar i have an alert from phpstorm to "mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_richieste_disponibili)" expected mysqli_result, got bool

Comment: hopefully you have sanitized your session

Comment: @Barmar, on top of that putting it in the **where** makes the **left** join an **inner** one

Comment: @DrPhil That's the point of switching to a prepared statement, isn't it? Less need to sanitize.

Comment: the original query has only 2 dynamic parameters. One of them is the system date, derived immediately above the SQL in question, so it is safe. The other one is professional category, which might come from user input, and that would require sanitizing. The rest is an overkill. The parameter placeholders are to replace dynamic composing of SQL with string interpolation. If there is no interpolation, there is no need for parameters, unless you plan to refactor and really change those...

Comment: @DrPhil It's not my question.

Comment: @Barmar, edited out, sorry

Comment: @DrPhil I am not understanding much from your interview, however no, I have not sanitized the $ _SESSION because I have no idea how to do it ... I only know that the $ _SESSION that gives me back the user's job category comes from when the user performs the login and then from the inputs of the login form

Comment: @DrPhil but. as I wrote to barmar's answer, his suggestion does not work and I wrote his suggestion in my further question, how can I solve?

Comment: To make the long story short, only **categoria_professionista** needs to be replaced , the rest is safe

Comment: @DrPhil is it safe even with the query I write in my working query question?

what should I do to make it safe?

but above all why does the barmar suggestion not work?

Comment: I would guess it doesn't work because you bind a wrong type. For the date you put **i**, while the original query had string. Replace 'isssii' with 'isssss'

Answer (score 0):

`$query->execute()` doesn't return a result object, it returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You need to call `$query->get_result` to get a result that you can fetch rows from.

And since `$oggi` is a string, you need the `s` type in `bind_param()`.

```
$query->bind_param('isssis', $zero, $inviata, $token_inserito, $richiesta_non_scaduta, $categoria_professionista, $oggi);

if ($query->execute()) {
    $query_richieste_disponibili = $query->get_result();

    while($row = $query_richieste_disponibili->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    ......
    <?php } 
}
```

Note that it only works this way if you use the mysqlnd driver. If not, you have to use `$query->bind_result()` and `$query->fetch()`.

Comment: edit my question and i write a code with your instruction but not work, check my question

Comment: I updated my answer with the corrected datatype for `$oggi`.